# JsonExtractor with OpenScript

Tags: openscript

Like http.solve and http.solveXpath is there anything similar for JSON.
In the snipped provided, I have to capture complete master node based on condition that the person should be either MD or MD,PhD.
Json syntax with Jmeter: ***$..[?(@.person_credentials == 'MD' || @.person_credentials == 'MD,PhD')]***
Looking for similar thing that can be implemented in OpenScript
Kindly provide ur inputs
Thanks,
Sumit

```html
[{
 "person_party_id": 3663409,
 "person_party_number": "1199490",
 "person_party_name": "Andrea Ward",
 "person_obj_version_num": 2,
 "person_profile_id": 31036987,
 "person_profile_obj_version_num": 2,
 "person_name": "Andrea Lee Ward",
 "person_pre_name_adjunct": {
  "lv_type_id": "TCA|CONTACT_TITLE",
  "code": "MS."
 },
 "person_first_name": "Andrea",
 "person_middle_name": "Lee",
 "person_last_name": "Ward",
 "person_name_suffix": null,
 "person_academic_title": null,
 "person_credentials": "HT(ASCP)",
 "person_ptr_number": null,
 "relationship_id": 1760699,
 "relationship_obj_version_num": 2,
 "relationship_party_id": 3959866,
 "relationship_party_number": "52898",
 "relationship_party_name": "Andrea Ward-Chester County Hospital-52898-52898-52898-52898",
 "relationship_party_obj_version_num": 2,
 "org_contact_id": 2006288,
 "org_contact_obj_version_num": 2,
 "is_generic": false,
 "email": {
  "contact_point_id": 1170409,
  "email_address": "andrea.ward2@uphs.upenn.edu",
  "object_version_number": 2
 },
 "phone": {
  "contact_point_id": 1170414,
  "phone_country_code": "1",
  "phone_area_code": "610",
  "phone_number": "431-5561",
  "phone_extension": null,
  "object_version_number": 2
 },
 "roles": [{
  "lv_type_id": "TCA|CONTACT_ROLE_TYPE",
  "code": "ELABUSER"
 }, {
  "lv_type_id": "TCA|CONTACT_ROLE_TYPE",
  "code": "PRIMREL"
 }],
 "contact_id": 3663409,
 "first_name": "Andrea",
 "last_name": "Ward",
 "credentials": "HT(ASCP)",
 "emails": [{
  "contact_point_id": 1170409,
  "email_address": "andrea.ward2@uphs.upenn.edu",
  "related_accounts": null,
  "object_version_number": 2
 }],
 "phone_numbers": [{
  "type": "Telephone",
  "contact_point_id": 1170414,
  "phone_country_code": "1",
  "phone_area_code": "610",
  "phone_number": "431-5561",
  "phone_extension": null,
  "related_accounts": null,
  "object_version_number": 2
 }, {
  "type": "Fax",
  "contact_point_id": 1170417,
  "phone_country_code": "1",
  "phone_area_code": "610",
  "phone_number": "430-2935",
  "phone_extension": null,
  "related_accounts": null,
  "object_version_number": 3
 }]
}, {
 "person_party_id": 3620546,
 "person_party_number": "208332",
 "person_party_name": "James Heald",
 "person_obj_version_num": 5,
 "person_profile_id": 15949851,
 "person_profile_obj_version_num": 2,
 "person_name": "James Irwin Heald",
 "person_pre_name_adjunct": {
  "lv_type_id": "TCA|CONTACT_TITLE",
  "code": "DR."
 },
 "person_first_name": "James",
 "person_middle_name": "Irwin",
 "person_last_name": "Heald",
 "person_name_suffix": null,
 "person_academic_title": null,
 "person_credentials": "MD,PhD",
 "person_ptr_number": null,
 "relationship_id": 1728597,
 "relationship_obj_version_num": 2,
 "relationship_party_id": 3927762,
 "relationship_party_number": "18195",
 "relationship_party_name": "James Heald-Chester County Hospital-18195-18195-18195-18195",
 "relationship_party_obj_version_num": 2,
 "org_contact_id": 1971610,
 "org_contact_obj_version_num": 2,
 "is_generic": false,
 "email": {
  "contact_point_id": 1167675,
  "email_address": "james.heald@uphs.upenn.edu",
  "object_version_number": 2
 },
 "phone": {
  "contact_point_id": 1167678,
  "phone_country_code": "1",
  "phone_area_code": "610",
  "phone_number": "431-5471",
  "phone_extension": null,
  "object_version_number": 2,
  "type": "Telephone"
 },
 "roles": [{
   "lv_type_id": "TCA|CONTACT_ROLE_TYPE",
   "code": "ELABEDSTADM"
  },
  {
   "lv_type_id": "TCA|CONTACT_ROLE_TYPE",
   "code": "ELABSTADM"
  },
  {
   "lv_type_id": "TCA|CONTACT_ROLE_TYPE",
   "code": "PRIMREL"
  }
 ],
 "contact_id": 3620546,
 "first_name": "James",
 "last_name": "Heald",
 "credentials": "MD,PhD",
 "emails": [{
  "contact_point_id": 1167675,
  "email_address": "james.heald@uphs.upenn.edu",
  "related_accounts": null,
  "object_version_number": 2
 }],
 "phone_numbers": [{
   "type": "Telephone",
   "contact_point_id": 1167678,
   "phone_country_code": "1",
   "phone_area_code": "610",
   "phone_number": "431-5471",
   "phone_extension": null,
   "related_accounts": null,
   "object_version_number": 2
  },
  {
   "type": "Fax",
   "contact_point_id": 1167683,
   "phone_country_code": "1",
   "phone_area_code": "610",
   "phone_number": "430-2935",
   "phone_extension": null,
   "related_accounts": null,
   "object_version_number": 2
  }
 ]
}]
```